# Zendcart - Merging existing userdatabase with zendcart database

Tags: php, hash, md5

I've just installed zendcart on my system, I tried merging the userdatabase of the site I already had with the zendcart database.

I've managed to port everything correctly, only the passwords don't seem to work.
my own system md5 hashes the passwords when they enter the DB, I don't know how zencart hashes it's password but as far as i can see is it nearly the same algorithm as I currently use only with 3 characters attached to it.

```
ex current password: sad97213sd123js123
ex zendcart pass: sad97213sd123js123:c1
```

How can I resalt my passwords to match zendcarts criteria, OR.. how can I edit zendcart to accept salted passwords generated by other means than zendcart's

Thank you in advanced

Comment: both of zendcart version are same?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, Only one of the systems is zencart, the other is a custom CMS

Comment: I believe by "zendcart" you mean "Zen Cart".

Answer (score 2):

Inside `class.zcPassword.php` (/includes/classes), you will find it:

```
  /**
   * Determine the password type
   *
   * Legacy passwords were hash:salt with a salt of length 2
   * php < 5.3.7 updated passwords are hash:salt with salt of length > 2
   * php >= 5.3.7 passwords are BMCF format
```

It describes the legacy compare it does before deciding what to do with the passwords, using the [`ircmaxell/password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library, right here:

```
  function detectPasswordType($encryptedPassword)
  {
    $type = 'unknown';
    $tmp = explode(':', $encryptedPassword); // try to break the hash in an array of 2 elements at :, first being the hash, second a suffix
    if (count($tmp) == 2) { // if it breaks...
      if (strlen($tmp [1]) > 2) { //...then check if 2nd has a length > 2...
        $type = 'compatSha256'; //...if it does, it's SHA2
      } elseif (strlen($tmp [1]) == 2) {//...if not, make sure it's == 2...
        $type = 'oldMd5';// ...just to confirm it's MD5
      }
    }
    return $type; // and return the string to be treated ahead
  }
```

**EDIT**: `//commented the code.`

As you can see, `:c1` is just the salt suffix (he `explodes` when he finds it) it reads to define which algorithm it should run to maintain backward compatibility (in your case, MD5) according to PHP version, that's why the hashes are the same.

I'd suggest you just remove the suffix at the end of all your passwords at `:` point or work upon that function and its dependencies as to ignore this checking.

Comment: You suggest that just removing :c1 from the password would work as well?

Comment: @Sjef92 If your new system doesn't run the same function Zen Cart runs to verify legacy hashing, then yes. The suffix won't give you any problems. If you have any doubts about implementing it, just dump your database into a backup file and do it! But I'm pretty sure about it.